# String replacement within multiple files

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, file-get-contents, str-replace

I have this function that will search and replace a given term inside a php file. 
When I pass an array with multiple files, the files are not modified and to avoid this problem I can only pass two files at time. How I can fix or improve this function? I think that the issue is because multiple files will occupy too much memory, but I'm not sure about this. Any help is appreciated. (I'm testing the function using a wordpress installation to find and replace the wp-prefix of some folders and files).

```
function wp_settings_edit(array $filename, array $patterns, array $replace){
  foreach($filename as $file){
    $wp_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/{$file}");
    foreach($patterns as $pattern){
      foreach($replace as $r){
      $wp_file_content = file_put_contents(__DIR__."/{$file}",str_replace("{$pattern}", "{$r}", $wp_file));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
 $files = array('wp-settings.php', 'wp-load.php');
 $patterns = array('wp-admin', 'wp-includes');
 $replace = array('admin', 'includes');
 wp_settings_edit($files, $patterns, $replace);
```

Comment: Why don't you just `$wp_file = str_replace($pattern, $r, $wp_file);` and then save the file only _ones_ after the `foreach ($patterns...)`-loop? Now you're saving the same file over and over in the inner foreach. If it is a memory issue, then those files need to be _very_ large.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will try, but I have three arrays, one for the files, one for the pattern and the last that will hold the replacing for the pattern. This is why I've nested the `foreach()`. I need to iterate all the three arrays.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should change your loops. I'm just saying that you should change the _variable_ inside the loop and then only use `file_put_contents(__DIR__."/{$file}", $wp_file)` _once_ per file, after the `foreach ($patterns...)`-loop.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok, but if I use `file_put_contents()` as you suggest, how I will change the `$replace` var that is an array of different values?

Comment: If you change the code inside the loop `$wp_file_content = file_put_contents(__DIR__."/{$file', ....` to what I suggested in my first comment and then add what I suggested in my second comment, the result would be the same as the current result, but you won't hammer your file system by re-saving the same file over and over.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your explainations and help. I've followed the suggestions proposed in this topic and now the script works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your files are very large – like hundreds of megabytes – you're certainly not running into memory limits. You are, however, doing this quite inefficiently.

You run a foreach loop on *both* the search and replace arrays, making an exponential increase in the number of file writes. If `str_replace()` only accepted string arguments, you could get rid of one of these loops. However, it accepts array arguments, so you can get rid of both.

```
function wp_settings_edit(array $filename, array $patterns, array $replace){
    foreach($filename as $file){
        $wp_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/$file");
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/$file", str_replace($patterns, $replace, $wp_file));
    }
}
```

---

This will improve efficiency and what's more, it will actually do the job you want it to. By doing a nested loop over both arrays, as in the original code, you would end up replacing *every* item in the search array with only the *first* element of the replacements array:

```
$s = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
$r = ["oof", "rab", "zab"];
$h = "Here is some foo text as well as some bar text and maybe some baz text.";
foreach ($s as $s1) foreach ($r as $r1) $h = str_replace($s1, $r1, $h);
echo $h;
```

Output:

> Here is some oof text as well as some oof text and maybe some oof text.

Comment: Ok, I was considering to remove just one loop, but I will try also with your suggestion. I assume from the example that all the arrays are looped when the `file_put_contents()` with `str_replace()` are called.

Comment: what do you mean with "you would end up replacing every item in the search array with only the first element of the replacements array." ? If I have two elements in the replacements array it will use only the first?

Comment: Think about it. You're looping over every element in the `$patterns` array. This is your list of things to replace. Within that loop, you go over every element in the `$replace` array, and do the string replacement. Obviously after the first iteration of the `$replace` array is completed, you'll have replaced everything from the `$patterns` array.

Comment: Given the example I just added to the answer, 1st iteration of `$r` you replace "foo" with "oof". 2nd iteration you try to replace "foo" with "rab", 3rd iteration you try to replace "foo" with "zab". Obviously 2nd and 3rd will do nothing since the replacement was done in the first. Then we start over again. 1st iteration you replace "bar" with "oof"...

Comment: Yes, I saw. Thanks to all for the clarifications and for help. Just another question related to this topic, Someone suggested me to use `htmlentities()` with `file_get_contents()` to load and output the `php` code before modify using `str_replace()`. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: If you're looking to replace characters that might have been converted to HTML entities, then yes. But given the wide support of Unicode in text editors (and certainly in browsers) there's really no need to use entities for any but the SGML-required characters of `<`, `>`, `&`, and `"`.

Comment: Of course, if you do that, then how do you perform the reverse before writing, without destroying your PHP and HTML markup? There's the rub.

Answer (score 0):

String replacement within multiple files.

```
    /*Multiple file str change */
     function multipleFileStrReplace($path,$string_to_replace,$replace_with){    
$fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST); 
foreach ($fileList as $item) {
    /*
    for txt file is following if condition =>   if ($item->isFile() && stripos($item->getPathName(), 'txt') !== false) 
    for other extension file then =>  if ($item->isFile() && stripos($item->getPathName(), 'other extention') !== false) 
    for all files search then just =>  if ($item->isFile()) 
    */
    if ($item->isFile() && stripos($item->getPathName(), 'txt') !== false) 
    {
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($item->getPathName());
        $file_contents = str_replace($string_to_replace,$replace_with,$file_contents);
        file_put_contents($item->getPathName(),$file_contents);
    }
    }
    }
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tests/replace/"; // Path to your textfiles 
    $string_to_replace="text you want to change";
     $replace_with="text you want to replace";
    multipleFileStrReplace($path,$string_to_replace,$replace_with);
      /* Single file sting change */
    function replace_string_in_file($filename, $string_to_replace, $replace_with){
    $content=file_get_contents($filename);
    $content_chunks=explode($string_to_replace, $content);
    $content=implode($replace_with, $content_chunks);
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
    }
   $filename="ve.txt";
    $string_to_replace="text you want to change";
    $replace_with="text you want to replace";
   replace_string_in_file($filename, $string_to_replace, $replace_with);
```

Comment: I think now i corrected my mistake to give answer in right way

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.